# Generating a link to a controller action in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm working on a Play application and need to generate links in a mixed Scala-HTML view that call controller actions. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447567/how-to-insert-link-to-controller-action-in-play-framework-2-0-template) question from a couple years ago that's similar to my situation, but the provided answers don't work for me.

The elements are generated in a loop so I can't manually insert the argument to the controller action, but nothing I've tried has worked. This is the line I have now:

```
ID: @{var fhirID = <processing for ID>; <a href='@routes.Users.fhirUserDetails(fhirID)'>fhirID</a>}
```

The accepted answer to the question I linked earlier effectively uses this structure too:

```
<a href='@routes.Application.show("some")'>My link with some string</a>
```

My issue here is twofold:

1) How can I have the variable fhirID passed to the controller action? My generated link simply has the text "fhirID" instead of what's generated by the first part of the statement.

2) Is the @routes.Users syntax correct? When I click the generated link, it literally attempts to render a page at /myapp/@routes.Users.fhirUserDetails(fhirID)

I realize I'm probably missing something very basic here- thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be not the `@routes` syntax (which you have completely correct) but rather a case of the Twirl engine not seeing where code ends and HTML begins (or something like that anyway...)

The line you've included, which has both a `var` and a semicolon, made me suspect this, and I've been able to reproduce the problem when I use that style.

My recommendation is to use the [`@defining` helper](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTemplates#Declaring-reusable-values) rather than `var` to get a scoped variable for use in your links, as follows:

```
ID: @defining(<processing for ID>) { fhirID => 
  <a href='@routes.Users.fhirUserDetails(fhirID)'>fhirID</a>
}
```

You can nest `@defining` blocks as deeply as you like if necessary, although it's probably better to make a call out to a reusable block if there's a lot of logic. I think this style makes for more-readable templates and also somehow looks more like "real Scala" :-)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I'm new to Play and Scala, as you can probably tell. Your suggestion works perfectly, much appreciated!